# React-table select row without checkbox

Tags: reactjs, react-table

Hello can I select a row in React-table without using the checkbox, I want just to use a click on the row that we want to select and then fetch the data from the selected row, if that's feasible can you provide me with an example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit: this answer is now outdated and is in need of revision. If you use React-Table at v7 please consult the official documentation for examples of how to make rows in your table clickable.

---

You need to register an event listener for your Row components, which would detect clicks. When listener is invoked, you will be able to change the state of your application to record that user has made a selection, which, in turn, can be used to change the appearance of the table so that users can "see" the selection happen (e.g. change the background color of the rows).

#### If using modern `react-table` based on custom Hooks API

You can pass `onClick` handler to `row.getRowProps` function to add it to all `tr` elements. You can also use `row.setState` to set row as `selected`.

```
<tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
    {rows.map((row, i) => {
        return (
            <tr {...row.getRowProps({
                onClick: () => { /* select the row here */ } 
            })}>
                {row.cells.map(cell => {
                    return /* your cell code */
                })}
            </tr>
        )
    })}
</tbody>
```

#### If using `react-table@v6` and earlier

Use `<ReactTable />` component prop called `getTrProps` which accepts a function which will receive information about the row and should return all props you want the `tr` element to receive — for example:

```
<ReactTable
    getTrProps={(_, row) => {
        return {
            onClick: () => { /* select your row here */ }
        };
    }}
/>
```

Comment: As of today and react-table version 7.7.0, the above solution gives an error:

`Argument of type '{ onClick: () => void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RowPropGetter<your_data_type> | undefined'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'onClick' does not exist in type 'RowPropGetter<your_data_type>'.ts(2345)`

Comment: This answer doesn't exactly cover what to do within onClick:. Suggest adding code to explain what needs to happen.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using react-table v7.7.0 custom Hooks API, For row level click follow below steps.

First pass `useRowSelect` hook to `useTable` like below.

```
   const tableInstance = useTable(
    {
        columns,
        data,
    },
    useRowSelect);
```

then you can add `onClcik` to `tr`

```
  <tbody>
    {rows.map((row, i) => {
      prepareRow(row)
      return (
        // <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
        <tr {...row.getRowProps()} onClick={() => { console.log(' row click ', row)}} >
          {row.cells.map(cell => {
            return (
              <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>
                {cell.render('Cell')}
              </td>
            )
          })}
        </tr>
      )
    })}
  </tbody>
```

Note: If `useRowSelect` not passed to `useTable`. `onClick` on `<tr>` wont trigger. Same way any option like filtering or sorting ect. pass respective hooks like `useFilters` or `useSortBy` to `useTable` will make it work.